# How to Read and Save Messages in Telegram and then Send message Using Python

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

I want to use Telegram client API.
I want to Run `run_until_disconnected()` for getting all messages in 24 hours and save them in Database. This Part is fine , I Wrote the code and its working fine . after some operations on the messages database , I want to send the result of that operation as a message to telegram (to channel or User). i wrote the code of sending message too but when i wanted to use , i get error of database is locked or session is locked...

What should I Do?

Comment: database locked error [reference](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/faq.html?highlight=database#sqlite3-operationalerror-database-is-locked)

Answer (score 0):

Please Read :: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/faq.html#id9

Solution according to docs :
if you need two clients, use two sessions. If the problem persists and you’re on Linux, you can use fuser my.session to find out the process locking the file. As a last resort, you can reboot your system.

If you really dislike SQLite, use a different session storage. There is an entire section covering that at [Session Files.](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/sessions.html#sessions)